# Web tex gift card plugin magento

Tags: email, plugins

Having trouble with the Web tex gift card plugin for Magento. When the user purchases a giftcard and fills out their info. The user then purchases the card. From that point an email is suppose to be sent to the user with the gift card information but it is never received. Has anyone encountered this using this plugin or has experience with the plugin. Anything would help at this point.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this..i am experiencing the same now..if you have any solution please share

Comment: It's hard to answer without more information - a lot of things could be causing this problem. But a good place to start might be their user guide: http://www.webtexsoftware.com/media/user-guides/Gift_Cards_User_Guide.pdf Other than that, try checking your PHP and Magento error logs.